# compute minimum clicks needed to perform in order to clear out a picture

Tags: c++

I have been trying to write a program for some question taken for competitive-coding of Cs-academy site.

The question is as following:

Suppose we were going through a bunch of black and white pictures and all of a sudden, a quirky idea struck to your mind – how many clicks does it take to convert all the white pixels into black and clear out a picture using brushes? So, we scanned and converted several pictures into binary data. Each pixel of the binary pictures are now represented by an integer, 0 for a black pixel and 1 for a white pixel.

To modify a picture, we can only use one of the three brushes each time:

+(plus) - When used, the pixels at the left, top, right and bottom of the current pixel are also colored in the same color.

x(cross) - When used, the pixels at the top-left, top-right, bottom-right and bottom-left of the current pixel are also colored in the same color.

*(star) - When used, all 9 pixels around the current pixel are also colored in the same color.

(Here is an illustration:https://publicmedia1.csacademy.com/public/1507909042-2157482298.png)

Each of these brushes, when used, works recursively. So if you color a pixel, its neighbors will get colored, then the neighbors of the neighbors, and so on.

Our task is to compute the minimum clicks you will have to perform with each brush in order to clear out a picture:
First we will have to compute the minimum clicks that are needed to clear the picture using only the + brush, then compute the minimum clicks that are needed to clear the picture using only the x brush and finally compute the minimum clicks that are needed to clear the picture using only the * brush.

Input begins with a single number t (1≤t≤100) which denotes the number of pictures to process.
Each test case begins with a line, which contains 2 space-separated integers w and h denoting the width and the height of the picture in pixels
(1≤w,h≤1001).
Following there will be h lines denoting the w pixel values (either 0 or 1) of each row of the picture.

For each test case output, 3 space separated integers which denote the minimum number of clicks needed to clear out the picture for each of the three brushes: +, x and *.

I wrote a program which calculates recursively - using separate functions - the count for each of 3 options:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int N = 101;
int mat[N][N];

void pluse(int mat[][N],int h , int w, int i,int j)
{
    if(i<0||j<0||i>=h||j>=w||mat[i][j]==0)
        return;
    mat[i][j]=0;
    pluse(mat,h,w,i+1,j);
    pluse(mat,h,w,i-1,j);
    pluse(mat,h,w,i,j+1);
    pluse(mat,h,w,i,j-1);

}
void cross(int mat[][N],int h, int w,int i,int j)
{
    if(i<0||j<0||i>=h||j>=w||mat[i][j]==0)
        return;
    mat[i][j]=0;
    cross(mat,h,h,i+1,j+1);
    cross(mat,h,w,i-1,j-1);
    cross(mat,h,w,i-1,j+1);
    cross(mat,h,w,i+1,j-1);
}
void star(int mat[][N],int h, int w,int i,int j)
{
    if(i<0||j<0||i>=h||j>=w||mat[i][j]==0)
        return;
    mat[i][j]=0;
    star(mat,h,w,i+1,j);
    star(mat,h,w,i-1,j);
    star(mat,h,w,i,j+1);
    star(mat,h,w,i,j-1);
    star(mat,h,w,i+1,j+1);
    star(mat,h,w,i-1,j-1);
    star(mat,h,w,i-1,j+1);
    star(mat,h,w,i+1,j-1);
}


int ans1(int mat[][N],int h , int w)
{
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i<h;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0;j<w;j++)
        {
            if(mat[i][j]==1){
                pluse(mat,h,w,i,j);
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int ans2(int mat[][N],int h , int w)
{
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i<h;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0;j<w;j++)
        {
            if(mat[i][j]==1){
                cross(mat,h,w,i,j);
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int ans3(int mat[][N],int h , int w)
{
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i<h;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0;j<w;j++)
        {
            if(mat[i][j]==1){
                star(mat,h,w,i,j);
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
int main()
{

    int t=1,h,w;
    int mat1[N][N],mat2[N][N],mat3[N][N];
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        cin>>w>>h;

           for(int i = 0;i<h;i++){
            for(int j = 0;j<w;j++){
                cin>>mat1[i][j];
                mat2[i][j]=mat3[i][j]=mat1[i][j];
            }
        }
        cout<<ans1(mat1,h,w)<<" "<<ans2(mat2,h,w)<<" "<<ans3(mat3,h,w)<<endl;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

However, my program can't give the correct the output and I have been not able to detect the reason for that.

For example, for the following input :

```
1011001
0010001
0001000
0000001
26 13
11111111111111111111111111
11111100111111111100111111
11110001111100111110001111
11000001111000011110000011
10000000111000011100000001
10000000000000000000000001
00000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000
10000000000000000000000001
10000110001000010001100001
11001111111100111111110011
11100111111100111111100111
11111111111111111111111111
```

I get the output :

```
111
000
```

whereas the correct output is actually:

```
5 6 4
2 18 2
```

**Update:**

I re-wrote my code as such :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int N = 1001;
char mat[N][N];

void pluse(char mat[][N],int h , int w, int i,int j)
{
    if(i<0||j<0||i>=h||j>=w||mat[i][j]=='0')
        return;
    mat[i][j]='0';
    pluse(mat,h,w,i+1,j);
    pluse(mat,h,w,i-1,j);
    pluse(mat,h,w,i,j+1);
    pluse(mat,h,w,i,j-1);

}
void cross(char mat[][N],int h, int w,int i,int j)
{
    if(i<0||j<0||i>=h||j>=w||mat[i][j]=='0')
        return;
    mat[i][j]='0';
    cross(mat,h,h,i+1,j+1);
    cross(mat,h,w,i-1,j-1);
    cross(mat,h,w,i-1,j+1);
    cross(mat,h,w,i+1,j-1);
}
void star(char mat[][N],int h, int w,int i,int j)
{
    if(i<0||j<0||i>=h||j>=w||mat[i][j]=='0')
        return;
    mat[i][j]='0';
    star(mat,h,w,i+1,j);
    star(mat,h,w,i-1,j);
    star(mat,h,w,i,j+1);
    star(mat,h,w,i,j-1);
    star(mat,h,w,i+1,j+1);
    star(mat,h,w,i-1,j-1);
    star(mat,h,w,i-1,j+1);
    star(mat,h,w,i+1,j-1);
}


int ans1(char mat[][N],int h , int w)
{
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i<h;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0;j<w;j++)
        {
            if(mat[i][j]=='1'){
                pluse(mat,h,w,i,j);
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int ans2(char mat[][N],int h , int w)
{
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i<h;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0;j<w;j++)
        {
            if(mat[i][j]=='1'){
                cross(mat,h,w,i,j);
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int ans3(char mat[][N],int h , int w)
{
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i<h;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0;j<w;j++)
        {
            if(mat[i][j]=='1'){
                star(mat,h,w,i,j);
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
int main()
{

    int t=1,h,w;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        cin>>w>>h;
        {
           char mat1[N][N],mat2[N][N],mat3[N][N];


           for(int i = 0;i<h;i++){
            for(int j = 0;j<w;j++){
                cin>>mat1[i][j];
                mat2[i][j]=mat1[i][j];
                mat3[i][j]=mat1[i][j];
            }
        }
        cout<<ans1(mat1,h,w)<<" "<<ans2(mat2,h,w)<<" "<<ans3(mat3,h,w)<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

However, for the input as above, I get the output

```
5 6 4
2 43 2
```

which is not correct,since the correct one should be :

```
5 6 4
2 18 2
```

Comment: I assume you copied and pasted the incorrect part of the input file.

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not reading the input correctly.

When you run `cin>>mat1[i][j]`, since `mat1[i][j]` is an integer the *entire line* of input will be read in.  So for the first (small) example, `mat[0][0]` will have the value 1011001 (one million, eleven thousand, and one).  What you should be doing is reading the input matrix a character at a time, then storing an appropriate value in your matrices, taking care to handle the newline correctly (and checking for errors in the input).

Another problem is that you don't output any spaces, so all three numbers run together to form one bigger number.

Comment: @ 1201ProgramAlarm  still get wrong output

Comment: @GaLIk That would be a different issue.  Since the problem (based on your update) is in the `cross` function, do you see any obvious problem with it?  Maybe a typo?